# Jooq insert will loss after application exited(using h2 local embeded file)

Tags: sql-insert, h2, jooq

The dsl context creation:

```kotlin
private val resource =
    Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResource("mock-data.db")!!

private val conn =
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:${resource.path};AUTO_SERVER=TRUE")

val appDslContext get():DSLContext = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.H2)
```

The insert statements:

```kotlin
 val alarmEvent = MonitorAlarmEventEntity(....)
 appDslContext.newRecord(MonitorAlarmEvent.MONITOR_ALARM_EVENT).apply {
            from(alarmEvent)
 }.insert()

 // works fine, I can see the inserted row was printed.
 println(
    appDslContext.select().from(MonitorAlarmEvent.MONITOR_ALARM_EVENT)          .fetchInto(MonitorAlarmEventEntity::class.java)
 )
```

After I rerun the application, I still only see one record, the previous record was lost.

Comment: H2 isn't a reliable database to store persistent data. jOOQ is doing the insert, but H2 doesn't flush the change to disk. Make sure that you shutdown your application correctly, leaving time for H2 to flush the data.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. That's utter nonsense. H2 is perfectly reliable. Just make sure that you properly close the context, and more importantly in this case, you use a writable file.

Comment: @Jorn H2 is not ACID compliant, this is not what I would call "reliable".

Answer (score 2):

I can see two possible problems: Either you aren't closing the H2 database properly, or you are not using a writable file.

To solve the first one, simply make sure that you clean up the `Connection` by calling `close()` before the application exits.

For the second one, I imagine that resources from your classpath are not directly writable. However, you are creating the connection using a path, so I'm not sure how that'll work out. I expect that you will see exceptions in your log if this is the problem. In either case, this is never going to work in production. You want your database file to be separate from your application code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got some inspiration from it. The real problem is that every time I build the application and rerun it, the db file is overwritten, it is copied from the `src/main/resources/mock-data.db`.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that every time I build the application and rerun it, the db file is overwritten, it is copied from the src/main/resources/mock-data.db`

```
//should not use files under the `build` directory, it will be overwritten by gradle
private val resource =
    Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResource("mock-data.db")!!
```